# RBAC: kubectl config use-context

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I've set up my k8s Cluster with an admin role and user role and I'm able to switch between roles using

> kubectl config use-context admin-context

or

> kubectl config use-context user-context

But I don't want the user role to be able to perform this command and switch between admin and user role.

So whats is the best solution? add token or username & password possibly?

Comment: Those `kubectl config` commands are just modifying a file on your machine (defaults to `~/.kube/config`), and for those to work it assumes that the admin and user credentials are already in that file (or somehow has permissions to retrieve the required credentials). Assuming you are the admin and other people are the users, you should only distribute user credentials to your users instead of admin credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the admin context and the accompanied user from your `~/.kube/config` file.